# Creating a generic object using a Class<?> variable

Tags: java

I have a generic class A, and I'm in a method where I have to create an instance of A based on the class the given object is. That is, I have:

```
public void (Object obj) {
  Class<?> c = obj.getClass();
  A<c> = ...;
}
```

However, on the third line Eclipse says that c cannot be resolved to a type. When I remove the generic parameter, I get "A is a raw type. References to generic type A should be parameterized."

What would be the correct way to go here?

Thanks.

Comment: Using capital `B` for an object reference is massively confusing to Java developers, particularly when you're using generics. `obj` would be better.

Comment: Elaborating on what @artbristol said, starting with a capital letter (e.g., CamelCase) denotes a class.  Starting with lowercase letters (e.g., camelCase) denotes a variable. `c` is not a type, `c` is an object of type `Class<?>`.  Talha, below, has the answer regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public <C> void (Object B) {
  Class<C> c = B.getClass();
  A<C> a = ...;
}
```

or even better

```
public <C> void (C B) {
  Class<C> c = B.getClass();
  A<C> a = ...;
}
```

or if you just need the Class

```
public <C> void (Class<C> clazz) {
  A<C> a = ...;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't really change the method signature in thia case. Is there no other way?

Comment: Nope. If the method or class does not declare a type in its signature, then you can't use generics in the method body

Comment: @Bohemian how is the type C inferred by the compiler when the method is invoked in the first case?

Answer (score 1):

`c` is an object. And you can only give the Class while defining the generic variable.

So `A<'ClassName'>` is the correct way to do that.